# reading specific number of rows in specific row groups from parquet file with pyarrow

Tags: python, parquet, pyarrow

I have a large parquet file that I want to sample, for example, I may want 7 rows from the first row group, 3 rows from the 2nd row group, 3 rows from 3rd row group, and I want to write these rows to a new parquet file. How can I do this with pyarrow? Preferably in a way that these row groups are read in parallel, or async using asyncio.

I've looked at ParquetFile.iter_batches(), but it doesn't seem to allow specifying the number of rows from each row group, is there a way to do this with pyarrow?